# How to update label in Second ViewController with information from First ViewController every second

Tags: swift2

I have an app that has two ViewControllers. On the first there is a count of current speed in realtime through CLLocationManager. Also there is a label that shows current speed with update by timer (NSTimer). In second ViewController there is another Label, where this current speed has to be shown too. It shows it, but don't update. I tried to set second timer (different ways: in first VC, in second VC - there is always was an error or just nothing).

Will be grateful for help, thanks!

**First VC**

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var currentSpeedLabel: UILabel!

    var manager = CLLocationManager()                       
    var currentSpeed: CLLocationSpeed = CLLocationSpeed()   
    var timer = NSTimer()                                    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        mapView.mapType = MKMapType.Hybrid                  

        trackingMe()                                        

    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func HUDMapView(sender: AnyObject) {

        speedCount()

    }

    @IBAction func findMe(sender: AnyObject) {

        trackingMe()
    }


    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        let userLocation: CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation

        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()

        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: userLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: userLocation.coordinate.longitude)
        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)

        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }


    func trackingMe() {

        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()

        mapView.showsUserLocation = true

        currentSpeedUpdate()
    }


    func currentSpeedUpdate() {

        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector: Selector("speedCount"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }


    func speedCount() {

        currentSpeed = manager.location!.speed
        currentSpeedLabel.text = String(format: "%.0f km/h", currentSpeed * 3.6)

    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: (UIStoryboardSegue!), sender: AnyObject!) {

        let speedController = segue.destinationViewController as! speedViewController

        currentSpeed = manager.location!.speed
        speedController.showSpeed = currentSpeedLabel.text

    }

}
```

**Second VC**

```
    import UIKit

class speedViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var secondSpeedLabel: UILabel!

    var showSpeed: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        secondSpeedLabel.text = showSpeed

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func back(sender: AnyObject) {

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    }

}
```

Comment: Add your map/tracking function to the second VC. Stop tracking in the first and start in the second.

Comment: but it will stop updating speed label in first VC, won't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Project Link](https://github.com/romainmenke/CoreLocationSingleton.git)

You could use a Singleton to hold the LocationManager. Then you can access it from all over your app. When you move to a second VC you can either change the delegate to the second VC or just get the needed data manually.

Remember that a delegate can only point to one "receiver". Changing the delegate will stop updates in the first VC. but since it is now a Singleton you can also store information in there about past locations / speeds. When dismissing the second VC get the stored data and update.

This will keep running until you call `stop()`

*The code was simplified a bit to illustrate the idea.*

**VC Code:**

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, TrackerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        Tracker.shared.delegate = self
        Tracker.shared.start()

    }

    func speedUpdate(speed: CLLocationSpeed) {
        print(speed)
    }
}
```

**Singleton Code:**

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class Tracker: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    static var shared = Tracker()

    private var manager = CLLocationManager()
    private var timer = NSTimer()

    var region : MKCoordinateRegion?
    var currentSpeed: CLLocationSpeed = CLLocationSpeed()

    weak var delegate : TrackerDelegate?

    private override init() {
        super.init()

        manager.delegate = self
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }


    internal func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()

        let userLocation: CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation
        let coordinates2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: userLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: userLocation.coordinate.longitude)
        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)

        region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinates2D, span: span)

        currentSpeed = userLocation.speed

        guard let del = delegate else {
            return
        }

        del.speedUpdate(currentSpeed)

    }


    func start() {

        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()

        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector: Selector("loopUpdate"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }

    func stop() {
        timer.invalidate()
    }


    internal func loopUpdate() {
        // restart updating
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()

    }
}
```

**Delegate for the Singleton:**

Add more functions, or more values to the current function to get more feedback.

```
protocol TrackerDelegate : class {

    func speedUpdate(speed:CLLocationSpeed)

}
```

Comment: @KharitonovAleksey there was an error in my answer. The delegate wasn't weak, creating a Strong Reference Cycle. Both the Tracker and the TrackerDelegate are updated.

Comment: Not yet, it was too late. I'll try it and will write about result

Comment: By the way, is there any way to talk to you without this comments? Still have some to ask, but don't wanna discuss in here. Thanks!

Comment: @KharitonovAleksey I added a link to a downloadable project

Comment: In your project still wasn't speed update in second VC, cause of in viewDidAppear was no tracking delegate, but it was in viewDidLoad. I set viewDidAppear like in first VC, and it start updating speed. Well, thanks for this concept! Now I know how to do it!

Comment: @KharitonovAleksey Thx for the feedback. will change it.